# PLSQL - Gerneric types in parent type

Tags: inheritance, plsql, types

I have a collection of plsql types that are very similar.

```
create or replace type OT_001 force as object (

   RAW         varchar2(3),
   INTERNAL    varchar2(3),

   constructor function OT_001 (
      RAW       in  varchar2
   ) return self as result,
   constructor function OT_001 (
      INTERNAL  in  varchar2
   ) return self as result,
   member procedure convert_to_raw_value,          -- accesses RAW and INTERNAL
   member procedure convert_to_internal_value      -- accesses RAW and INTERNAL
)
```

All other types OT_002, ... are identical except for RAW and INTERNAL having different varchar2 dimensions. constructors and member procedures do not care about the actual dimensions of the varchars RAW and INTERNAL and the code is identical in all of them.

Is it possible to define a super type OT_SUPER that can hold the constructors and the member procedures, but using RAW and INTERNAL as "generic types", which are then made precise (w.r.t. their dimensions) in the subtypes OT_001, OT_002, ...?

I tried to define a super, but RAW and INTERNAL need then to be defined in the super, but then the subtypes don't allow me to overwrite their type definitions.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adobj/inheritance-in-sql-object-types.html#GUID-C9382BAD-3513-4CFB-9D4D-D3BC5B581AA8): _A subtype cannot drop or change the type of an attribute it inherited from its parent; it can only add new attributes._